# PayPal: Internal Server Error on Create Payment

Tags: c#, .net, api, paypal

I am using paypal API for .NET to create payments.

My exact code in Console Application:

```
        // Get a reference to the config
        var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();

        // Use OAuthTokenCredential to request an access token from PayPal
        var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();

        var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);

        var p = new Payment();
        p.intent = "sale";

        p.payer = new Payer();
        p.payer.payment_method = "credit_card"; //paypal or credit_card

        var t = new Transaction();
        t.amount = new Amount();
        t.amount.currency = "GBP";
        t.amount.total = "10.00";

        t.amount.details = new Details();
        t.amount.details.subtotal = "6.00";
        t.amount.details.tax = "2.00";
        t.amount.details.shipping = "2.00";

        t.item_list = new ItemList();
        t.item_list.items = new List<Item>();

        var i1 = new Item();

        i1.quantity = "1";
        i1.name = "OBJETO TESTE";
        i1.price = "6.00";
        i1.currency = "GBP";

        i1.sku = "TESTE";

        t.item_list.items.Add(i1);

        var a = new ShippingAddress();
        a.recipient_name = "ADDRESS";
        a.line1 = "LINE1";
        a.line2 = "LINE2";
        a.city = "LONDOM";
        a.country_code = "GB";
        a.postal_code = "NW19EA";

        t.item_list.shipping_address = a;

        p.transactions = new List<Transaction>();
        p.transactions.Add(t);

        p.redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
        p.redirect_urls.cancel_url = string.Format("{0}{1}", "http://localhost:3161/", "Order/CancelPayment");
        p.redirect_urls.return_url = string.Format("{0}{1}", "http://localhost:3161/", "Order/CompletePayment");

        var payment = Payment.Create(apiContext, p);
```

If I change payment method to paypal, its working. if I send credit_card I get error 500.

debug_id: 30e0f1bb08d3f

configuration: live

Comment: When you use `credit_card` as the payment method, are you also including the [funding instrument details for the credit card](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/PaymentWithCreditCard.aspx.cs#L67)?

Comment: Not because the docs is not as required (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payer-object). On my system I do not have this information, it can not be treated dynamically in paypal?

Comment: Payment method of `credit_card` indicates you are using PayPal to process a credit card transaction that is not associated with a PayPal buyer account.  If you want PayPal to process a transaction where the buyer uses a credit card they have tied to their PayPal account, then you only need to use `paypal` as the payment method.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merchants from **UK** cannot make Direct(Credit Card) Payments using REST API.
You will need to upgrade your account to PRO to make use of Direct Card Payments.
Only US merchants can make direct card payments in REST API without a PRO account.

Comment: That really did not know, thanks for the reply. The strange thing is the return to be with error code 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: @CleitonAdrianoHoffmann yes,  that's kinda incorrect error message